# Best way to launch a WPF ".application" Application

Tags: javascript, wpf, launching-application

What is the best way (in JavaScript) to launch a ".application" Application through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to keep it simple:

```
window.navigate('pathToApplication/MyApp.application');
```